# Getting previous window value for processing late events

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I am looking for a way to setup windowing to allow for lateness as well as let me calculate values based on previous values calculated for the session.

My sessions values are overall a unique identifier, and should never have collisions, but sessions can technically come in at anytime.  On most sessions, most events are processed over 5 minutes,  Allowing lateness of 1 day should satisfy any late events.

```
  stream
    .keyBy { jsonEvent => jsonEvent.findValue("session").toString }
    .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(5)))
    .allowedLateness(Time.days(1))
    .process { new SessionProcessor }
    .addSink { new HttpSink }
```

For each session I am finding the max value of a field, and checking that a few events did not happen(if they do happen, they will make the max value field zero).  I decided to create a `ProcessWindowFunction` to do this.

```
Class SessionProcessor extends ProcessWindowFunction[ObjectNode, (String, String, String, Long), String, TimeWindow] {

   override def process(key: String, context: Context, elements: Iterable[ObjectNode], out: Collector[(String, String, String, Long)]): Unit = {
      //Parse and calculate data
      maxValue = if(badEvent1) 0 else maxValue
      maxValue = if(badEvent2) 0 else maxValue          
      out.collect((string1,string2,string3, maxValue))
   }
}
```

This works fine prior to allowing for late events.  When a late event comes through, `maxValue` is recalculated and is outputted to `HttpSink` again.  I am looking for a way so that I can calculate the delta of previous `maxValue` and late `maxValue`.

I am looking for a way to determine:

1. If the call to the function is from a late event(I do not want to double count total number of sessions)
2. What the new data is, or if there is a way, to store the previous calculated value.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: New code used for ValueState

KafkaConsumer.scala

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONDeserializationSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingProcessingTimeWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time


object KafkaConsumer {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
      env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime)
      val properties = getServerProperties
      val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode]("test-topic", new JSONDeserializationSchema, properties)
      consumer.setStartFromLatest()
      val stream = env.addSource(consumer)

      stream
        .keyBy { jsonEvent => jsonEvent.findValue("data").findValue("query").findValue("session").toString }
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
        .allowedLateness(Time.days(1))
        .process {
          new SessionProcessor
        }
        .print
      env.execute("Kafka APN Consumer")
    }
  }
```

SessionProcessor.scala

```
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow

class SessionProcessor extends ProcessWindowFunction[ObjectNode, (String, String, String, Long), String, TimeWindow] {

  final val previousValue = new ValueStateDescriptor("previousValue", classOf[Long])

  override def process(key: String, context: Context, elements: Iterable[ObjectNode], out: Collector[(String, String, String, Long)]): Unit = {

    val previousVal: ValueState[Long] = context.windowState.getState(previousValue)
    val pVal: Long = previousVal.value match {
      case i: Long => i
    }
    var session = ""
    var user = ""
    var department = ""
    var lVal: Long = 0

    elements.foreach( value => {
      var jVal: String = "0"
      if (value.findValue("data").findValue("query").has("value")) {
        jVal = value.findValue("data").findValue("query").findValue("value").toString replaceAll("\"", "")
      }
      session = value.findValue("data").findValue("query").findValue("session").toString replaceAll("\"", "")
      user = value.findValue("data").findValue("query").findValue("user").toString replaceAll("\"", "")
      department = value.findValue("data").findValue("query").findValue("department").toString replaceAll("\"", "")
      lVal = if (jVal.toLong > lVal) jVal.toLong else lVal
    })

    val increaseTime = lVal - pVal
    previousVal.update(increaseTime)
    out.collect((session, user, department, increaseTime))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that does something similar. It's hopefully reasonably self-explanatory, and should be easy enough to adapt to your needs.

The basic idea here is that you can use `context.windowState()`, which is per-window state made available thru the context passed to a ProcessWindowFunction. This windowState is in fact only useful for windows that fire multiple times, since each new window instance has a newly initialized (and empty) windowState store. For state that's shared across all windows (but still keyed), use `context.globalState()`.

```
private static class DifferentialWindowFunction
  extends ProcessWindowFunction<Long, Tuple2<Long, Long>, String, TimeWindow> {

  private final static ValueStateDescriptor<Long> previousFiringState =
    new ValueStateDescriptor<>("previous-firing", LongSerializer.INSTANCE);

  private final static ReducingStateDescriptor<Long> firingCounterState =
    new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("firing-counter", new Sum(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE);

  @Override
  public void process(
      String key, 
      Context context, 
      Iterable<Long> values, 
      Collector<Tuple2<Long, Long>> out) {

    ValueState<Long> previousFiring = context.windowState().getState(previousFiringState);
    ReducingState<Long> firingCounter = context.windowState().getState(firingCounterState);

    Long output = Iterables.getOnlyElement(values);
    if (firingCounter.get() == null) {
      // first firing
      out.collect(Tuple2.of(0L, output));
    } else {
      // subsequent firing
      out.collect(Tuple2.of(firingCounter.get(), output - previousFiring.value()));    
    } 
    firingCounter.add(1L);
    previousFiring.update(output);
  }

  @Override
  public void clear(Context context) {
    ValueState<Long> previousFiring = context.windowState().getState(previousFiringState);
    ReducingState<Long> firingCounter = context.windowState().getState(firingCounterState);

    previousFiring.clear();
    firingCounter.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for, I understand what it's trying to do, but I don't see any my `ValueStates` changing between calls.  Note: I had to switch from `ProcessingTimeSessionWindows` to `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` since it did not want to allow WindowStates in merging windows(which is fine).  I edited OP with new code, `pVal` is always 0 despite me seeing the same sessionId coming in multiple times and the `increaseVal` being non-zero.

Comment: Are you sure there are late events? If you want to share your new code I'll take a look.

Comment: I made updates to OP with the two files.  I am pretty sure that the events are late because I am seeing print output more than once per session(and I believe windows are processed once if there is no lateness).  I also have the windows very short(5 seconds) and extra processing prints are coming in more than 5 seconds later.   Let me know if I can provide you anything else.  Thanks for all of the help so far!

Comment: I don't see why it isn't working as you expect. But don't forget to implement a clear() method on the SessionProcessor. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that merging windows support WindowStates if you use ReducingState rather than ValueState.

Comment: So I believe what is happening is that the messages are indeed not coming in late, instead a new window is starting.  Perhaps I am mistaken about allowing lateness, but if I have `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5))` and `allowedLateness(Time.seconds(55))` shouldn't all of the events for a session in the next minute be apart of the same window?  Or is it just events that should have been processed in the 5 seconds that are part of that window.  Hopefully this isn't too off topic for this question, I may have to create a new question to figure out how to do this for my use case.

Comment: Only events whose timestamps fall within the 5 second period that defines the window's boundaries will be included as part of the window. Setting allowed lateness delays the window's eventual destruction (for 55 sec in this case), and allows for late firings as late events arrive, but those events have to fall within the window boundaries (the 5 secs).